# Approximate image with pixels from reference photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, effects

In order to color grade my image in same sense of a reference photo, I'd like to approximate my image with the pixel colors from the photo, but on different places. Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible; it's what the Topaz Labs ReStyle plugin does for a living, so to speak. (In ReStyle, you'd save the unmodified example image as a preset, then apply it to your image and tweak as necessary.) It's also possible without a plugin, using multiple targeted hue/saturation layers, but rather less easy. Since this is essentially "buy a plugin" and I'm not aware of any direct competitors (which likely exist and should be considered), I'm not going to put it forward as an answer.

Comment: @StanRogers Thanks for that information. I found out [how the effect works](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918259/67338) and will implement it on my own, plus releasing it as open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I better understand what you're looking for. In Photoshop, you can open 2 images and then go to Image>Adjustments>**Match Color**. This will get your photos closer to one another. You may still need to tweak your colors with either a Color Balance, Hue, or Photo Filter adjustment layer.

Comment: My goal is to take all the pixels of a reference image, throw them into a mixing bowl and arrange them in a way so that an image near my image appears. I think it's some form of example based color grading.

Comment: See my new response above.